# Google app engine - disable automatic start of new deployed service versions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-build

I'm using cloud build to automatically deploy new version of app when a specific github branch is updated.

Everything works great but I'd like to deploy the new version without starting it, keeping my previous version running.
I really prefer to schedule start of the new version in specific hours, but when cloud build finish the process, my new version is automatically running.

How can I change this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid that the new version is started you can deploy using the `--no-promote` [flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/deploy#--promote).

To use this flag when deploying using gcloud just need to add it to the command and deploy like this:

`gcloud app deploy --no-promote`

To implement this as part of the CD with Cloud Build then you can edit the cloudbuild.yaml to add the flag like this:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['app', 'deploy', '--no-promote']
  timeout: '1600s'
```